# Create Image from numerical array of data in php

Tags: php, arrays, image-processing, blob

Am dealing with webservices in my project. i am not sure about the bankend logic like what kind of method they used to store images in database.

This is the response i got as my profile image from server

```
Array
(
 [0] => -119
 [1] => 80
 [2] => 78
 [3] => 71
 [4] => 13
 [5] => 10
 [6] => 26
 .
 .
 .
 [3778] => 123
 [3779] => 60
 [3780] => -82
 [3781] => -57
 [3782] =
)
```

How do convert this numerical array into PNG Image?

I have created a new image file and put all contents into that file using

```
file_put_contents('downloads/myImage.png', $profileImage);
```

$profileImage variable contains the above array.

this code creates a new image with some dump of datas. I know i have missed something by doing this. please help me with this.

i have used this same code to create PDF files from the server in this same project. that's working fine. thats why i tried with the same code to get my image. But its not working with images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear — I can't tell if you want to save the PNG file somewhere or deliver it as the response to an HTTP request. Also, you seem to imply that `$profileImage` is an array variable, but provide it as an argument to `file_put_contents()`, which expects a string.

But either way, the binary data you are being provided with looks fine.

If `$profileImage` is an array of signed byte values, then you can convert it to a string of binary data with the following command"

```
$rawPNG = implode(array_map('chr',$profileImage));
```

If you need to, you can then use `file_put_contents()` to write this data to a file. (The function is binary-safe, so there shouldn't be any problems.)

Alternatively, if you want to return a PNG image to a web client, just echo it with an appropriate Content-Type header:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
die ($rawPNG);
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. I got the image. Its working fine now. i need to store the image in my server so that i have convert the array into a string( as per your instruction ) then write that into a png file. Now i need to revert this procedure to send back the image to server while updating profile details.

Comment: i have tried to revert the same process for my upload functionality without success. i have used these code `$data = file_get_contents($path); 
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $data);`
actually i am getting an array with all unsigned integers. what i need to get is array of signed bytes. expected the result array is of (23000 records) and the result what am getting is about 175000 recods(~). help me with that.

Comment: we have the same functionality in our andriod app for the same project. there we get the byte array using `JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; ++i) {
    array.put(byteArray[i]);
}` this code. how can i do the same in php???

Comment: PHP doesn't have a byte storage class per se. But if you want to convert a character string into an array of signed values, just replace `C*` with `c*` (lowercase) in your call to `unpack()`. Does that help?